# Javascript - callbacks & promises - Allow jsmediatags to gather album artwork before executing function

Tags: javascript, callback, async-await, mp3

I have been attempting something that I believe to be relatively straight-forward in Javascript (for upwards of 12 hours) related to callbacks and/or promises.

Heads Up:  I'm using Rails with an `.js.erb` file but that isn't relevant to my question which is more focused on Javascript; only shown to illustrate the larger problem.

I'm using jsmediatags to read metadata from mp3s on a remote host (mostly focused on gathering the album artwork).  Each "article" on my site correlates to multiple audio files (`@related_titles`), so I am looping over each one (local variable `url`) and gathering the artwork and then displaying them in a coverflow plugin--this means that `jsmediatags.read` is executed once for every mp3 that is processed.   The problem is... jsmediatags doesn't finish reading all of the artwork prior to the coverflow plugin initializing.  Even though I'm relatively new to js, it seems like the perfect use of a callback function.

Right now, I've been forced to introduce a 8500ms `setTimeout` function before executing the `makeitrain` function (which inits the coverflow).  It works but it isn't reliable across all devices (when they are under load) and it isn't a elegant solution.

Let's assume that there are 3 mp3s in `@related_titles`.  In order to show that the code is not executing in the proper order (not waiting for the callback?), I've added console logging.

**Received Output:**

```
Gathered all art!  Now I will callback and render the Coverflow
Initing Coverflow since gatherArtwork completed/we have art!
Gathering album art for title...
Gathering album art for title...
Gathering album art for title...
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Gathering album art for title...
Gathering album art for title...
Gathering album art for title...
Gathered all art!  Now I will callback and render the Coverflow
Initing Coverflow since gatherArtwork completed/we have art!
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
function gatherArtwork(_callback) {

  // Read each of the mp3s to gather artwork ('url' == local var for mp3)
  <% @related_titles.each do |url| %>
      jsmediatags.read("<%= url['mp3'] %>", {
          onSuccess: function(tag) {

              console.log('Gathering album art for title...');

              // Convert the image contents to a Base64 encoded str
              var tags = tag.tags;
              albumartwork = _arrayBufferToBase64(tags.picture["data"]);

              // Append to the coverflow list a `<ul><li> </li></ul>` for each mp3
              // The 'albumartwork' Base64 image str is also appended here
              $("#coverflow-item-list").append('<ul><li>...</li></li>');

          }
      });
  <% end %>

  console.log('Gathered all art!  Now I will callback and render the Coverflow');
  _callback();

}

// Gather artwork MUST complete fully before the `makeitrain` function runs (callback)
function renderCoverflow() {
    gatherArtwork(function() {
      console.log('Initing Coverflow since gatherArtwork completed/we have art!');
      makeitrain();
    });
}

// Execute 'renderCoverflow' which will gather art and then "makeitrain"!
renderCoverflow();
```

Comment: You should read about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises so you can avoid this kind of confusing code.  You know you are heading the wrong direction when you start using `setTimeout` to try to synchronize your calls.

Comment: Yes, I knew it was only a temporary solution to get my larger project working.  I knew I'd have to come back and remove the `setTimeout` which is what I am trying to do now.   To be clear, I am trying to replace `setTimeout` with a proper callback or promise solution.  Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best would be promises for this. I copied the basic `new jsmediatags` with a promise wrapper from https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags. May need some fine tuning but intent is to  provide basic concept outline for you

I am not a rails dev so will leave it to you to output your `related_titles` array to a javascript variable by printing JSON which then gets read automatically by javascript as array

```
<script>
  var urls = // echo json array
<script>
```

With that done the rest of the script can be put in separate file or directly in page, whichever you prefer

```
// helper function to get tag info and return promise that resolves with the base64 result
function getTags(url) {      
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      new jsmediatags.Reader(url)
        .read({
          onSuccess: (tag) => {                
            resolve( _arrayBufferToBase64(tag.tags.picture["data"]));
          },
          onError: (error) => {                
            reject(error);
          }
        });
    });
}

// create array of getTags() promises
let promises = urls.map(url => getTags(url))

Promise.all(promises).then(results=>{
  // `results` is array of all the base64 values same order as the urls array
  // loop over the results and add what is needed to DOM

  // then call cover flow

}).catch(err=> console.log('One of the requests failed'))
```

Comment: So incredibly helpful, I will try this and get back to you!   Regarding your comment to have me get `urls` populated properly for Javascript, are you just saying I need to get the format of `urls` into a json-formatted array of hashes?

Comment: charlietfl, this will work even with standard js, right?  The jsmediatags link you provided only references the promises approach in relation to nodeJS and I'm running Rails.   I'll try it shortly and find out regardless, but I sure hope my misery will be over!  Thanks again!!!

Comment: Yes Promise will work in browser. And as for url data, not sure what you have or need. Could be array of strings if that's all that is needed and that's what I based my code on. If it is array oj objects then would pass whatever property the url is in into the `getTags()`

Comment: Thank you so so much!  IT WORKS!!!  I about fell over when I saw it work for the first time... this was really taking my days up.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't (ever) duplicate your js code on server like you did, the result of:

```
function gatherArtwork() {
  // Read each of the mp3s to gather artwork ('url' == local var for mp3)
  <% @related_titles.each do |url| %>
      console.log("<%= url['mp3'] %>");
  <% end %>
}
```

is:

```
function gatherArtwork() {
  // Read each of the mp3s to gather artwork ('url' == local var for mp3)
      console.log("url1");
      console.log("url2");
      ....
      console.log("urln");
}
```

So this is mean that you are sending a lot of unnecessary code to the user (your JS file is bigger now).
Instead, you can do:

```
/**
  * Load all arts from urls
  */
function gatherArtwork(urls) {
  // Read each of the mp3s to gather artwork ('url' == local var for mp3)
  for(url in urls) {
      console.log(url);
  }
}
```

The advantage of using this is also now you can declare `gatherArtwork`function as `async` and do the following:

```
async function gatherArtwork(urls) {
  for(url in urls) {
     await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     jsmediatags.read("<%= url['mp3'] %>", {
       onSuccess: function(tag) {
         console.log('Gathering album art for title...');
         // Convert the image contents to a Base64 encoded str
         var tags = tag.tags;
         albumartwork = _arrayBufferToBase64(tags.picture["data"]);

         // Append to the coverflow list a `<ul><li> </li></ul>` for each mp3
         // The 'albumartwork' Base64 image str is also appended here
         $("#coverflow-item-list").append('<ul><li>...</li></li>');
         resolve(tag);
       },
       onError: function(error) {
         reject(error);
       }
    });
  });
  }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
await gatherArtwork(urls)
console.log('Gathered all art!  Now I will callback and render the Coverflow');
makeitrain();
```

Watch out! The function that fire the code above should be `async` too. if you want to avoid this, you should use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Thank you so much Michael.  I'll try both answers that were submitted and see where I land.  Apparently, jsmediatags has native promises built-in per https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags and @charlietfl.  Looking into this now...

Comment: Also, when you say to use `Promise.all`, are you saying change:  `await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {` to `await new Promise.all(function(resolve, reject) {` ?

Comment: no, if you are going with `Promise.all` method, you need to remove all `await/async` and just return an array of promises in `gatherArtwork` so your cal looks like: `gatherArtwork(urls).then((values) => {/* all promisies are done */ })`

Comment: Thanks so much Michael!!  I ended up going with the other answer, just because it leverages the native promise wrapper built into jsmediatags, but your answer was helpful too and I will definitely use this concept in the future!